# Why do I have to cast in "First Unique Character in a String" Problem?

Tags: java, casting

This solution doesn't work.

```
 public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    HashMap map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
            map.put(s.charAt(i), 2);
        }
        else{
            map.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        
        if(map.get(s.charAt(i)) == 1){
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

But it works now when I cast the value of the Hashmap to int

> (int)map.get(s.charAt(i)) == 1

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
    HashMap map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
            map.put(s.charAt(i), 2);
        }
        else{
            map.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        
        if((int)map.get(s.charAt(i)) == 1){
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

I used:

> System.out.print(map.get(s.charAt(i)).getClass().getName());

to confirm that the value of the map should already be an integer so I don't understand why I am getting this error when I try to submit to leetcode without casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();`

`HashMap` is a [*raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), essentially equivalent to `HashMap<Object, Object>`. Hence the compiler cannot detect the type of the value being `Integer` unless you cast.

Always specify the generic type at declaration, and you can use the diamond operator at the initialization side:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can also use the `var` keyword if you keep the type information at the right-hand side:

```
var map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the HashMap like this instead:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```